# How to override spring.config.import in tests?

Tags: spring, spring-boot

I am experimenting with git2consul and `spring-boot-config-consul` approach to externalize configuration. Solution itself works correctly (ergo, configuration is correct).

To fetch configuration from consul I use `spring.config.import` in `application.yml`

```
   spring:
      config:
         import: "consul:"
```

and this works just fine. However, in one of integration tests, I want to replace consul configuration with predefined set of props as well as disable consul completely. Therfore I try

```
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
        "spring.config.import=classpath:/consul/defaults.yml",
        "spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false",
        "spring.profiles.active = test"
})
public class MySpecialCaseITTest{}
```

However, this fails due to

```
java.lang.IllegalStateException: Unable to load config data from 'consul:'
```

If I provide invalud classpath, then it fails complaining about non existing file (which is correct) which means that most probably I end up with effective configuration of

```
`spring.config.import="classpath:/consul/defaults.yml,consul:`
```

or the other way around.

How can I effectively OVERRIDE value of `spring.config.import` set in `application.yml`? (using CLI arguments has the same effect)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that [according to Spring doc](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/features.html#features.external-config.files.importing)

> Imports are processed as they are discovered

It means that all imports from specified profiles are evaluated. Since you defined import for consul config in your default `application.yal`, it will always be evaluated.

Here is the ticket about this behavior in spring-cloud:
https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-config/issues/1877

And, for now, there is no fix. Only workarounds available for this problem:

Workaround 1: don't use imports in default `application.yml`. Instead, create a new profile, `application-consul.yaml`, and use it where you need to load configs from Consul. You can run the spring app with multiple profiles like `consul,prod`.

Workaround 2: define a separate property for import path and replace it in tests (tested on spring boot 3.1.0):

```yaml
import-path="consul:"
spring.config.import=${import-path}
```

```java
@TestPropertySource(properties = {
    "import-path=classpath:/consul/defaults.yml",
    "spring.cloud.consul.enabled=false",
    "spring.profiles.active = test"
})
```

Comment: I was thinking about using separate profile to confiugure consul alone as well. I need to check if your 2nd workaround will work in SpringBoot 2

Comment: Isuing intermediate property works in SP2 .Thank you, it is  practically the same as what I tried to do.

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help you